# DRF ModelSerializer CharField with a source does not appear in validated_data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this:

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='app_user')
```

And I have a serializer for this class:

```
class AppUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name')

    class Meta:
        model = AppUser
        fields = ('first_name',)

def create(self, validated_data):
    first_name = validated_data.pop('first_name')
    user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', first_name=first_name, last_name='test')
    app_user = AppUser.objects.create(**validated_data, user=user)
    return app_user
```

But when I try to create a user with this serializer, although I send a parameter called `first_name` I get this error:

> KeyError: 'first_name'

And when I run the program in debug mode I can see that `validated_data` is empty!

Another point is that when I add `write_only` to the field it appears in `validated_data`, but I don't want the field to be `write_only`!

It seems that something is making this field `read_only`, How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validated_data doesn't contain `first_name` data directly. It's included into nested `user` dictionary. So you should first get `user` data in create method:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    first_name = user_data.pop('first_name')
    user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', first_name=first_name, last_name='test')
    app_user = AppUser.objects.create(**validated_data, user=user)
    return app_user
```